# Can I determine type of an awk variable?

Tags: awk, variable, gawk

I have the gawk version of awk. In [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Variable-Typing) part of gawk manual, it is stated that awk variables have "attributes", which are used to determine how to treat them in various operations.

For example, a string that is of the form `" +3.14"` which is obtained by parsing the input has the `STRNUM` attribute, which makes it behave as a number in a comparison with a number, whereas the same string defined in an awk program does not have this attribute.

OTOH, a string like `"3.14"` apparently has `STRNUM` attribute, even if it was defined in the program because the code `x = "3.14" { print x == 3.14 }` prints 1. Whereas if we define it as `"+3.13"` or `"   3.14"`, it does not have `STRNUM` attribute since the `x = "+3.14" { print x == 3.14 }` or `x = "   3.14" { print x == 3.14 }` prints 0.

I think that such succinctness in variable typing may cause subtle bugs. Hence, in order to aid in debugging such situations, is there a way to learn what type of "attributes" a variable has? I.e, can we learn what is the type of a variable?

Comment: awk variables don't have types. Everything is a string unless arithmetic operators are used. Also show how you parse +3.14 from the file as unless you use arithmetic operators on it, then it will be treated as a string `+` inlcuded.

Comment: @123 I know that unless I use arithmetic operators on it, then it will be treated as a string. _But_ if I use arithmetic operators on it, it will be treated as a number, whereas this is not the case for such string manually defined in an awk program.

Comment: If you use arithmetic operators on any variable then it will be treated as a number no matter how it was defined.

Answer (score 6):

Awk has [4 types](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html): "number", "string", "numeric string" and "undefined". Here
is [a function](http://github.com/svnpenn/velour/blob/8ebe900/libo.awk#L5-L22) to detect that:

```
function o_class(obj,   q, x, z) {
  q = CONVFMT
  CONVFMT = "% g"
    split(" " obj "\1" obj, x, "\1")
    x[1] = obj == x[1]
    x[2] = obj == x[2]
    x[3] = obj == 0
    x[4] = obj "" == +obj
  CONVFMT = q
  z["0001"] = z["1101"] = z["1111"] = "number"
  z["0100"] = z["0101"] = z["0111"] = "string"
  z["1100"] = z["1110"] = "strnum"
  z["0110"] = "undefined"
  return z[x[1] x[2] x[3] x[4]]
}
```

For the third argument of `split`, you need something that is not a space, and
not part of `obj` or else it will be treated as a delimiter. I chose `\1`
based on [Stéphane suggestion](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/304458). The function does internal `CONVFMT`
toggling, so it should return the correct result regardless of `CONVFMT` value
at the time of the function call:

```
split("12345.6", q); print 1, o_class(q[1])
CONVFMT = "%.5g"; split("12345.6", q); print 2, o_class(q[1])
split("nan", q); print 3, o_class(q[1])
CONVFMT = "%.6G"; split("nan", q); print 4, o_class(q[1])
```

Result:

```
1 strnum
2 strnum
3 strnum
4 strnum
```

Full test suite:

```
print 1, o_class(0)
print 2, o_class(1)
print 3, o_class(123456.7)
print 4, o_class(1234567.8)
print 5, o_class(+"inf")
print 6, o_class(+"nan")
print 7, o_class("")
print 8, o_class("0")
print 9, o_class("1")
print 10, o_class("inf")
print 11, o_class("nan")
split("00", q); print 12, o_class(q[1])
split("01", q); print 13, o_class(q[1])
split("nan", q); print 14, o_class(q[1])
split("12345.6", q); print 15, o_class(q[1])
print 16, o_class()
```

Result:

```
1 number
2 number
3 number
4 number
5 number
6 number
7 string
8 string
9 string
10 string
11 string
12 strnum
13 strnum
14 strnum
15 strnum
16 undefined
```

The notable weakness is: if you provide "numeric string" of any of the
following, the function will incorrectly return "number":

- integer
- `inf`
- `-inf`

For integers, this is explained:

> A numeric value that is exactly equal to the value of an integer shall be
>   converted to a string by the equivalent of a call to the `sprintf` function
>   with the string `%d` as the `fmt` argument

However `inf` and `-inf` behave this way as well; that is to say that none of
the above can be influenced by the `CONVFMT` variable:

```
CONVFMT = "% g"
print "" .1
print "" (+"nan")
print "" 1
print "" (+"inf")
print "" (+"-inf")
```

Result:

```
 0.1
 nan
1
inf
-inf
```

In practice this doesn’t really matter, see the [Duck test](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_test).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I didn't say it was only a problem with the original awk implementation but with those implementations based on (derived from) it. That includes the awk of current versions of Solaris, FreeBSD, macOS and I suppose most other commercial Unices. Yes, that's a bug, but a widespread one with an easy work around. Note that gawk is almost as ancient (1986). The [_real awk_](https://github.com/onetrueawk/awk) still maintained by Brian Kernighan (the `k` in `awk`) does incorporate features from gawk.

Comment: Any way to have this check if the value is an array as well?

Answer (score 5):

From GNU Awk 4.2, there is a new function `typeof()` to check this, as indicated in the release notes from the beta release:

> 15. The new typeof() function can be used to indicate if a variable or array element is an array, regexp, string or number.  The isarray() function is deprecated in favor of typeof().

So now you can say:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {print typeof("a")}'
string
$ awk 'BEGIN {print typeof(1)}'
number
$ awk 'BEGIN {print typeof(a[1])}'
unassigned
$ awk 'BEGIN {a[1]=1; print typeof(a)}'
array
$ echo ' 1 ' | awk '{print typeof($0)}'
strnum
```

Comment: @Stéphane it is funny how `echo ' 1 ' | awk '{print typeof($0)}'` returns "strnum", while `awk 'BEGIN{print typeof(" 1 ")}'` return "string". Any hint on why is like this?

Comment: that's the whole point of this Q&A. See my answer or Steven's

Answer (score 4):

With gawk, `PROCINFO["identifiers"]` is an [array with information about variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Auto_002dset). Use it like: `PROCINFO["identifiers"]["your_variable_name"]`. The possible value returned is one of "array", "builtin", "extension", "scalar", "untyped", "user".

There is only a general `scalar`, which includes both strings and numbers. The `gawk` interpreter just tries its best with doing stuff.

There is a reason why sometimes you'll see a seemingly redundant `variable + 0` somewhere, to ensure `awk` treats the variable as a numeric one.

See this paragraph for some of the [trickery with implicit conversions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Strings-And-Numbers.html#Strings-And-Numbers).

Answer (score 4):

To clarify, only *strings* that are coming from a few sources (here quoting [the POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)):

> 1. Field variables
> 2. Input from the getline() function
> 3. FILENAME
> 4. ARGV array elements
> 5. ENVIRON array elements
> 6. Array elements created by the split() function
> 7. A command line variable assignment
> 8. Variable assignment from another numeric string variable

are to be considered a *numeric string* if their value happens to be numerical (allowing leading and trailing blanks, with variations between implementations in support for hex, octal, inf, nan...).

The `"3.14"` literal string constant is a string, not strnum, because it doesn't come from one of those sources.

```
x = "3.14"; if (x == 3.14) print "yes"
```

prints yes, but that's because it's doing a lexical comparison (depending on the implementation, using `memcmp()`, `strcmp()` or `strcollate()`) of `3.14` and the conversion to a string (via the `CONVFMT` format string, `%.6g` in `gawk` and many other implementations) of that `3.14` number. That is, with that value of `CONVFMT`, `(x == 3.14)` is the same as `(x == "3.14")`.

`(x < 12)` would be false, because `3.14` sorts lexically after `12` (same as `("3.14" < "12")`). With `CONVFMT = "%.6e"`, `(x == 3.14)` would also return false because that becomes `("3.14" == "3.140000e+00")`.

On the other hand, in:

```
"echo \"3.1400 \"" | getline x
if (x == 3.14) print "yes"
if (x < 12) print "yes"
```

`yes` is printed twice whatever the value of `CONVFMT`, because a numerical comparison is performed. `x` is a strnum because it comes from `getline` and has a numeric value.

It still retains its string value though. `print x` will print `"3.1400 "` whatever the value of `OFMT` or `CONVFMT`.

And:

```
"echo 3.14 foo" | getline x
if (x == 3.14) print "yes"
```

Doesn't print `yes`. `x` comes from `getline` but doesn't have a numeric value (because of the `foo`). It is a normal string, as if you had written `x = "3.14 foo"`. Still, you will be able to do numeric operations with it:

```
print x + 1
```

Will output `4.14`. Above, because it is involved in a numeric operation, the string is converted to a number by looking at the initial part (past the eventual blanks) that looks like a number at the start of a string.

So `(x+0 == 3.14)` and `(x+0 < 12)` will also return true. `x+0` is numeric, so we've got a numeric comparison.

Note that `inf`, `nan`, `Infinity` are not recognised as the floating point `inf` or `nan` special values as constants, but in several `awk` implementations, you can use `("inf"+0)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If the gawk < 4.2(RHEL7 default version: gawk 4.0.2)
As fedorqui answer and the gawk 4.2 [release note](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2017-10/msg00004.html)

**14. The new typeof() function can be used to indicate if a variable or array element is an array, regexp, string or number.**

```
$ cat test.txt 
11.11
-0
ext4
0
xfs
0.123
11111.111111
-3333.3333333

$ cat test.txt | awk '{if($1!=0 && $1+0==0) {print $1" non-numeric"} else {print $1" numeric"} }'
11.11 numeric
-0 numeric
ext4 non-numeric
0 numeric
xfs non-numeric
0.123 numeric
11111.111111 numeric
-3333.3333333 numeric
```

If the gawk >= 4.2

```bash
$ cat test.txt | awk '{{print $1" ,"typeof($1)}}'
11.11 ,strnum
-0 ,strnum
ext4 ,string
0 ,strnum
xfs ,string
0.123 ,strnum
11111.111111 ,strnum
-3333.3333333 ,strnum
```

Comment: (1) Would you care to add some explanation?  (See the other answers for examples.)  (2) What happens on versions ≥ 4.2?  (3) What does this do for values that come from the input?  For example, `printf '%s\n' '-0' | awk …` … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.