# How do I search files using grep for multiple strings (intersection search)

Tags: command-line, grep, file-search

How do I use grep to search a nested directory structure for files containing **all** words in my search pattern?

I want to grep for files that contain multiple words - let’s use foo bar and bah. I can do `grep -rl foo |xargs grep -rl bah| ...etc`, but is there an easier way to do this? I know I can use -F for a file of strings to search for, but I believe this still searches for the strings using an OR operator (union), and I need to use the AND operator (intersection).

Comment: @dopeghoti Not a duplicate, looking across the entire file for search strings.

Comment: Do you want to match the words ***as words***, or do ‘‘food’’ and ‘‘bargain’’ count?

Comment: I’m okay with either a direct full-string match or a wildcard (‘foo.*’) match.

Answer (score 3):

**`find`** + **`awk`** solution:

```
find . -type f -exec awk '/\<foo\>/{ p1=1 }/\<bar\>/{ p2=1 }/\<bah\>/{ p3=1 }
                          p1 && p2 && p3{ print FILENAME; exit }' {} +
```

---

`awk` program details:

- `/\<foo\>/{ p1=1 }/\<bar\>/{ p2=1 }/\<bah\>/{ p3=1 }` - on encountering each of the needed patterns - set respective flag
- `p1 && p2 && p3` - as soon as all the patterns are found:

  - `print FILENAME` - print the current *filename/filepath*
  - `exit` - exit script execution immidiately

Comment: Thanks, but I’m hoping for a grep-only solution; find+awk (or sed) will work but I’m hoping to remember commands with as much streamline as possible.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is similar to @RomanPerekhrest's answer.  The main difference is that it takes advantage of the fact that you can get `awk` to process the entire input in one go by setting the record separator (`RS`) to something that will never match anything in the input (e.g. `^$`). In other words, slurp in the entire file and search it as if it was a single string.

e.g.

```
find . -type f -exec \
  awk -v RS='^$' '/foo/ && /bar/ && /baz/ { print FILENAME }' {} +
```

This will list all files beneath the current directory (`.`) that contain **ALL** of the regular expressions `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`.  If you need any or all the regular expressions to be treated as whole words, surround them with word-boundary anchors `\<` and `\>` - e.g. `\<foo\>`.

This also runs faster because it doesn't fork `awk` once for every file. Instead, it runs `awk` with as many filename arguments as will fit into the command line buffer (typically 128K or 1 or 2M characters on modern-ish systems)....e.g. if `find` discovers 1000 files, it will only run `awk` once instead of 1000 times.

**Note:** This requires a version of `awk` that allows `RS` to be a regular expression.  See [Slurp-mode in awk?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304457/slurp-mode-in-awk) for more details and an example of how to implement a limited form of "slurp mode" reading in other versions of awk.

**Also Note:** This will read the entire contents of each file found into memory, one at a time.  For truly enormous files, e.g. log files that are tens of gigabytes or larger in size, this may exceed available RAM or even RAM+SWAP.  As unlikely as it is, if it happens it can cause serious problems (e.g. on Linux, the kernel will start killing random processes if it runs of of RAM and SWAP).

Comment: I must mention the initial condition "*for files containing all **words*** ..." (a slight hint)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yeah and when asked what he wanted he said he's happy with a direct match or a wildcard `foo.*`.  I think you're placing an emphasis on "words" that the OP didn't intend.   He probably doesn't want to match foo, bar, or baz either - they're just example regular expressions for him to replace with whatever it is he actually wants to search for.

Comment: Do you really need `nextfile`, given that you’re treating each file as a single record?

Comment: @G-Man nope.  You're right.  I just tested it and it works the same without `nextfile`.  I added it out of habit - it's an optimisation (skip to next file on first match...or more generally, skip or exit <whatever> on first success) that works well when not slurping the entire file.

Answer (score 0):

For a logical AND like this, I usually fall back on `awk`:

```
awk '/foo/ && /bar/ && /bah/ { print }' /path/to/file
```

Comment: Op says ` to search a nested directory structure for files`, maybe you need to do `find -type f ...` and then `awk`.

Comment: this will check for presence of all 3 patterns on a LINE, but not within the whole TEXT

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `grep` with `-P` [(Perl-Compatibility)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) option and [positive lookahead regex `(?=(regex))`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to look for the words in any order in a single line or in a whole file and recursively in all files found start from current directory.

```bsh
grep -rlP '(?s)(?=.*?\bfoo\b)(?=.*?\bbar\b)(?=.*?\bbah\b)' .
```

- `(?s)` here is DOTALL modifier and allows *dot* to match even \newlines, we would use `(.|\n)*?` too between words as well as `[\s\S]*?`.
- in `\bWORD\b`; `\b` are word boundaries anchors.

With input as follows:

> ```
> ==> file1 <==
> foo here and bar
> bah
> and of file1
>
> ==> file2 <==
> foo then bar and bah
>
> ==> file3 <==
> foo foobarbah ba
>
> ==> file4 <==
> this is foo bar bahh
> bah
> ```

The output is:

```
./file1
./file2
./sub-dir/file4
```

Comment: Hmm, is there anyway to do this without the perl-specific regex? I’m hoping for something slightly more bash generic ( I also don’t know perl!)

Comment: surly there is, but you don't need to know `perl`, even most of us and you are using `grep` without knowing how its code written, isn't it?   :   )