# AWK: prevent field splitting of arguments passed to external utilities

Tags: shell, awk

From inside an AWK script, I can pass variables as arguments to external utilities:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    filename = "path_to_file_without_space"
    "file " filename | getline
    print $0
}'
```

But if the variable contains spaces,

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    filename = "path to file with spaces"
    "file " filename | getline
    print $0
}'
```

I get the error

```
file: cannot open `path' (No such file or directory)
```

Suggesting that the argument is split on whitespace, much the same way that a shell splits unquoted variables on whitespace.  I thought of disabling shell field splitting by setting the shell's IFS to null, like so

```
"IFS= file " filename | getline
```

Or by setting IFS to null before running the AWK command, but neither option makes any difference.  How can I avoid this field splitting?

Comment: IFS does NOT control parsing of _commands_ in a shell, it only controls _some_ _later_ steps, like 'expanding' `$var` or `$(cmd)` (if outside doublequotes) or executing `read v1 v2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to quote the name of the file:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    filename = "path to file with spaces"
    "file \"" filename "\"" | getline
    print
}'
```

or, as suggested in comments, for ease of reading,

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    DQ = "\042" # double quote (ASCII octal 42)
    filename = "path to file with spaces"
    "file " DQ filename DQ | getline
    print
}'
```

or, assuming this is part of a larger `awk` program,

```awk
BEGIN {
    SQ = "\047"
    DQ = "\042"
}

BEGIN {
    name = "filename with spaces"
    cmd = sprintf("file %s%s%s", DQ, name, DQ)

    cmd | getline
    close(cmd)

    print
}
```

That is, close the command when done with it to save on open file handles. Set up convenience "constants" in a separate `BEGIN` block (these blocks are executed in order). Create the command using `sprintf` into a separate variable.  (Most of these things are obviously for longer or more complicated `awk` programs that needs to present a readable structure to be maintainable; one could also imagine writing a `dquote()` and `squote()` function that quotes strings)

The left hand side of the "pipe" will evaluate to the literal string

```
file "path to file with spaces"
```

Basically, using `cmd | getline` makes `awk` call `sh -c` with a single argument, which is the string `cmd`. That string therefore must be properly quoted for executing with `sh -c`.

The technical details are found in  [POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html):

> `expression |  getline [var]`
>
> Read a record of input from a stream piped from the output of a command. The stream shall be created if no stream is currently open with the value of `expression` as its command name. The stream created shall be equivalent to one created by a call to the `popen()` function with the value of expression as the command argument and a value of `r` as the `mode` argument. As long as the stream remains open, subsequent calls in which `expression` evaluates to the same string value shall read subsequent records from the stream. The stream shall remain open until the `close` function is called with an expression that evaluates to the same string value. At that time, the stream shall be closed as if by a call to the `pclose()` function. If `var` is omitted, `$0` and `NF` shall be set; otherwise, `var` shall be set and, if appropriate, it shall be considered a numeric string (see Expressions in awk).

The `popen()` function referred to here is the C `popen()` library function.  This arranges for he given string to be executed by `sh -c`.

You'll have exactly the same issue with `system()` if executing a command using a filename with spaces, but in that case the C library's `system()` function is called, which *also* calls `sh -c` in a similar way as `popen()` (but with different plumbing of I/O streams).

So, no amount of setting `IFS` to anything would help if `sh -c` was invoked with the single argument

```
file path to file with spaces
```

Comment: In awk scripts where I need many quotes, I set up a var as `-vq=\"` or even `{q=sprintf("%c",34)}`

Comment: Always: BEGIN { SQ = "\047"; DQ = "\042"; }

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Thanks, that makes it more readable.

Comment: I would normally assemble the whole command like: cmd = sprintf ("file %s", SQ filename SQ); (a) Easy to debug. (b) You should close the pipework with close (cmd) after use.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Thanks, I've incorporated that. I will not add more style stuff as it distracts from the actual issue.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant, but that makes the assumption that you're on an ASCII-based system (not too unreasonable an assumption these days). Using `-v sq="'" -v dq='"'` would make it more readable and portable.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas But inconvenient to use unless wrapped up in a shell script.

Comment: If not wrapped up in a shell script, then it's just `sq = "'"; dq = "\""`. Still more readable and more portable.

Comment: House style. My awk scripts are generally wrapped in '..', so putting `sq = "'"` inside a begin breaks it. I usually write my whole awk as a separate variable assignment, so the command line is some distance away, isolating the -v and -F options from the awk code. I dislike mixing escaped and syntactic quotes. Basically, I'm playing the %ages to avoid typos (especially hard-to-see ones). I also tend to declare `BLK = " ";`, `NIL = "";`, `NUL = "\0";`, and `stderr = "cat 1>&2";` for readability and compatibility reasons.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant I'm not entirely sure, but I _think_ Stéphane possibly, maybe, implied using `dq` and `sq` as environment variables.

Comment: @Kusalananda I'm seeing -v as specifying awk variables as command-line options. Env vars, or awk assignments in place of file args, would not like spaces around the `=`. I despair of `sq = ENVIRON["sq"];` Maybe Stéphane refers to  a shebang-awk file. I rely on my visual cues, and I trust my readership (3 or 4 benighted souls) will forgive me, but I prefer `gsub (DQ, BLK)` over `gsub ("\"", " ")`.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant :-) I will leave this comment thread be for now, as it's on a topic tangential to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  That helps quite a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Note that for arbitrary file names, spaces are the least of your worries. Consider for instance a file called `$(reboot)` or `foo;reboot #whatever` or `foo|reboot|bar`...

`awk` calls `sh` to interpret command lines in its `cmdline | getline`, `print | cmdline`, `system(cmdline)`, so when building the command line out of arbitrary input, it's critical to properly escape arguments to avoid command injection vulnerabilities.

Quoting in shells is a tricky business. Shells have a great number of different quoting operators (`'...'`, `"..."`, `\`, `$'...'`, `$"..."`) all but `'...'` being potentially unsafe as they don't escape **every** character (in particular, they don't escape the `\` character which is a dangerous one as its encoding is also found in the encoding of other characters in some charsets).

It's also important not to use the old `` `...` `` form of command substitution in the shell code as they introduce another level of backslash processing.

Say you have the arbitrary file name in an environment variable:

```
#! /bin/sh -
FILE="${1?No file provided}"
export FILE

awk -v q="'" '
  function shquote(s) {
    gsub(q, "&\"&\"&", s)
    return q s q
  }
  BEGIN {
    cmdline = "file -- " shquote(ENVIRON["FILE"])
    if ((cmdline | getline) > 0)
      print "The first line of \""cmdline"\" output was \""$0"\"."
    else
      print "Could not read a line from \""cmdline"\" output."
    if (close(cmdline) != 0)
      print cmdline" failed."
  }'
```

Above, `shquote()` takes a string as argument and quotes it for `sh` by enclosing it in single quotes (the safest quotes), except that single quotes in the string itself are changed to `'"'"'`, that is a closing `'`, followed by a `'` quoted with `"..."` followed by another `'` that reopens another single-quoted string.

You'll notice above a few other hints at other possible caveats:

- you need a `--` to make sure your file name is not taken as an option if it starts with `-`.
- the output of that `file` command is not guaranteed to be on a single line, especially if the filename itself contains newline characters. After all, the newline character is as valid as any in a file name. `getline` only reads one record, records being lines by default. See [Slurp-mode in awk?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/304457) for hints as to how to read the whole output.
- that output could also not have any line at all. To tell that from an empty first line, you'd need to check the return value of `getline`.
- it's a good idea to check the exit status of the command as well to report problems if need be. That's done with looking at the value returned by `close()`. Note however that there are variations between `awk` implementations on how that value encodes the exit status. The only common thing between all is that that value is 0 when the command succeeds (exits with a 0 exit code).

Comment: Thank you. I never knew close(pipe) returned an exit status.