# using awk with if and z option

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

when I want to check if a returned value is integer or not I use this in bash script:

```
  if [ -z "$value" ]
    then
    echo 0
    else
    echo $value
  fi
```

I was trying to use `z` option in awk with if. for example i have this line:

```
PRIMARY SECONDARY CONNECTED 350 800
```

I tried using this:

```
/bin/awk '{if( -z $1){print "0"}else{print $1}}' script
```

no matter i replace `$1` with `$2` or `$3` or `$4` or `$5` it always return `0`. am I using awk in a wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, there is no `-z` test in `awk`, and the `-z` test in the shell tests for empty strings, not integers.

In `awk` you would do the following to test whether a variable is empty (and output a zero if it is, or its value if it's not):

```
if (value == "")
    print 0
else
    print value
```

or,

```
print (value == "" ? 0 : value)
```

For example:

```
$ awk -F '\t' '{ print ($1 == "" ? 0 : $1) }' file
```

to print a zero for those lines whose first tab-delimited value in the input is empty, and the actual value otherwise.

Possibly related (if you want to find the type of a variable in `awk`):

- [Can I determine type of an awk variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281271)

Comment: would you please explain how can i use these with awk? i get syntax error.

Comment: @BlackCrystal The code in my answer is awk code. I'll add an example that calls awk from the shell as soon as I'm at a computer (now on phone).

Comment: @BlackCrystal Updated.

Answer (score 2):

`-z` in shell will not tell you "if a value is integer or not", but whether its length is > 0.

You can do the same in awk with `length` -- `if(length($1)) ...`

If you want to check if a variable or field is a number or not in `awk`, you could do this:

```
 if($1+0 || $1~/^[+-]?0/) ...
```

Your `if(-z $1)` expression will simply negate the unset variable `z`, which will yield `0`, and then append the `0` to the `$1` field, creating a non-empty string which will be always considered TRUE, **even if** `$1` was the empty string `""` or the number `0`.

Comment: would you please explain what is `($1+0 || $1~/^0/)` doing?

Comment: `$1+0` checks if the numeric value of `$1` is non-zero (which will be if `$1` is already a non-zero number or is a string which starts with a non-zero number), and `$1~/^0/` checks if it's the number 0 or a string starting with `0` (not `"foo"`, or `""`, which will also evaluate to 0 when converted to a number)

Comment: If you're only interested in non-negative integers, you can get away with this `$1~/^[0-9]/`. For numbers in general, you'll have to implement the whole of `strtod()` in slow awk if you don't like my hack.

Comment: One idiom in `awk` is to test `$1+0 == $1`, that is to force the value to a number and see if it compares equal to the original. (Strings get turned to `0` in the process, and that doesn't compare equal to the original string.) This accepts anything `awk` thinks is a number, like `123.34e5`, or `-0`.

Comment: @ilkkachu that won't do. not even for your example: `echo | awk '{$1="123.34e5"; print $1, $1+0, $1+0 == $1}'`. You shouldn't try with fields, because  `awk` not only splits a line with `IFS`, it also turns into numbers the fields which look like numbers (pass the strtod-test). `echo 0 | awk '{print $1 ? "yes" : "no"; $1="0"; print $1 ? "yes" : "no"}'`

Comment: @pizdelect, mm, it works for me in `echo 123.34e5 | awk '{ print $1, $1+0, $1+0 == $1 }'`. But perhaps you're right, perhaps it does some autodetecting.

Comment: It seems you still don't believe me, despite the evidence. That's documented behavior (in mawk's manpage and in the POSIX standard -- "Each
          array element shall have a string value when created and, if
          appropriate, the array element shall be considered a numeric
          string" -- though not in gawk's, even if gawk is acting the same). Some other awk implementation have different bugs, they may work differently because `==` will do a numeric comparison, etc. -- anyways, my point stands: your trick is not reliable.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
/bin/awk '{if( x$1 == x){print "0"}else{print $1}}' script
```

there is no `-z` option in awk.

Comment: that will only check if `$1` is non empty (ie is not `""`), which you could do just as well with `if($1) ...`

Comment: @pizdelect `if ($1)` would not trigger if `$1` is zero.

Comment: @Kusalananda not if it's `"0"`.

Comment: @pizdelect The test `if ($1)` would not test whether `$1` is empty.  It would test whether `$1` is non-zero.  That's what I mean.

Comment: @Kusalananda Yeah, it's a bit of confusion. I know that `echo 0 | awk '$1'` won't print anything. `echo | awk '{$1="0";if($1)print$1}` will print `0`, though. And it will test whether $1 is empty: `echo :foo | awk -F: '$1'` won't print anything, etc.