# Why does gawk treat `0123` as a decimal number when coming from the input data?

Tags: input, gawk, numeric-data

According to `$ man gawk`, the `strtonum()` function can convert a string into a number:

> `strtonum(str)`           Examine  str, and return its numeric value.  If
>                           str begins with a leading 0,  treat  it  as  an
>                           octal  number.  If str begins with a leading 0x
>                           or 0X, treat it as a hexadecimal number.   Oth‐
>                           erwise, assume it is a decimal number.

And if the string begins with a leading `0`, the number is treated as octal, while if it begins with `0x` it's treated as hexadecimal.

I've run these commands to check my understanding of the function:

```
$ awk 'END { print strtonum("0123") }' <<<''
83

$ awk 'END { print strtonum("0x123") }' <<<''
291
```

The string `"0123"` is correctly treated as containing an octal number and converted into the decimal number `83`.
Similarly, the string `"0x123"` is correctly treated as containing an hexadecimal number and converted into the decimal number `291`.

Now, here's what happens if I run the same commands, but moving the numerical strings from the program text to the input data:

```
$ awk 'END { print strtonum($1) }' <<<'0123'
123

$ awk 'END { print strtonum($1) }' <<<'0x123'
291
```

I understand the second result which is identical as in the previous commands, but I don't understand the first one. Why does gawk now treat `0123` as a decimal number, even though it begins with a leading `0` which characterizes octal numbers?

I suspect it has something to do with the [strnum attribute](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Variable-Typing.html#Variable-Typing), because for some reason <sup>1</sup>, gawk gives this attribute to `0123` but not to `0x123`:

```
$ awk 'END { print typeof($1) }' <<<'0123'
strnum

$ awk 'END { print typeof($1) }' <<<'0x123'
string
```

<sup>1</sup> It may be due to a [variation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/364116/289772) between awk implementations:

> To clarify, only  strings that are coming  from a few sources  (here quoting the
>   POSIX spec): [...] are to be considered  a numeric string if their value happens
>   to be numerical  (allowing leading and trailing blanks,  **with variations between
>   implementations in support for hex, octal**, inf, nan...).

---

I'm using gawk version `4.2.62`, and the output of `$ awk -V` is:

```
GNU Awk 4.2.62, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 3.1.4, GNU MP 6.1.0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is related to the generalised `strnum` handling in version 4.2 of GAWK.

Input values [which look like numbers](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Variable-Typing.html#Variable-Typing) are treated as `strnum` values, represented internally as having both string and number types. “0123” qualifies as looking like a number, so it is handled as a `strnum`. `strtonum` is designed to handle both string and number inputs; [it looks for numbers first](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/tree/builtin.c?id=fa9c6b921f784ad6f35f36b65635969ae4fade2d#n3590), and when it encounters an input number, returns the number without transformation:

```
NODE *
do_strtonum(int nargs)
{
        NODE *tmp;
        AWKNUM d;

        tmp = fixtype(POP_SCALAR());
        if ((tmp->flags & NUMBER) != 0)
                d = (AWKNUM) tmp->numbr;
        else if (get_numbase(tmp->stptr, tmp->stlen, use_lc_numeric) != 10)
                d = nondec2awknum(tmp->stptr, tmp->stlen, NULL);
        else
                d = (AWKNUM) force_number(tmp)->numbr;

        DEREF(tmp);
        return make_number((AWKNUM) d);
}
```

Thus “0123” becomes the number 123, and `strtonum` returns that directly.

“0x123” doesn’t look like a number (by the rules defined in the link given above), so it is handled as a string and processed as you’d expect by `strtonum`.

A number is defined as follows [in AWK](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tab41):

> The input string is decomposed into two parts: an initial, possibly empty, sequence of white-space characters (as specified by [*isspace*()](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isspace.html)) and a subject sequence interpreted as a floating-point constant.
>
> The expected form of the subject sequence is an optional `'+'` or `'-'` sign, then a non-empty sequence of digits optionally containing a <period>, then an optional exponent part. An exponent part consists of `'e'` or `'E'`, followed by an optional sign, followed by one or more decimal digits.
>
> The sequence starting with the first digit or the <period> (whichever occurs first) is interpreted as a floating constant of the C language, and if neither an exponent part nor a <period> appears, a  is assumed to follow the last digit in the string. If the subject sequence begins with a <hyphen-minus>, the value resulting from the conversion is negated.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, the only way to bypass the fact that `strtonum()` looks for numbers first is to use a dummy string concatenation and force the numeric string to become a literal string: `$ awk '{ print strtonum($1 "") }' <<<'0123'`. Could you clarify which rule in the link of the user manual explains why `0x123` doesn't look like a number? Because it looks like a number to me; at least that's how I would write `291` in hexadecimal in an awk progam text. Is it because of the alphabetical character `x`?

Comment: See the description in [the POSIX `awk` specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tab41): a number is a possibly empty sequence of spaces, followed by “+” or “-”, followed by digits forming a floating-point decimal number. “x” isn’t allowed in a number, so it’s a string.

Comment: Note that if POSIXLY_CORRECT is set `gawk` treats `0x10` as a 16 number (as required (by mistake) by some older version of the POSIX spec, but now only allowed)

Comment: @user938271 an explicit or implicit `split()` in awk will create "dual-nature" values which are both strings and numbers. This does not happen with other functions: `awk 'BEGIN{s="0 1 2"; split(s, a); z = substr(s, 1, 1); print a[1], z, (a[1] == z), a[1] ? "yes" : "no", z ? "yes" : "no"}'`. Same thing with `$1` as with `a[1]`. As I already mentioned in a couple of comments / answers, this is not properly specified in the standard, but only vaguely alluded to. It probably deserves its own Q&A.